# angularjs this is undefined while using $.proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, angularjs

I have an UserApplications object wich queries the server for a list of applications the user is registered to looking like this:

```
    data.factory('UserApplications', function($resource){
        return $resource('/users-rs/api/getapplications/:locale',{},{
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {locale: 'locale'}, isArray: true}
        });
    });
```

I call it in another service and want to save the data as a JSON string using the angular-localstorageservice module (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) which is passed to the constructor of the service like this:

```
function UserService(UserInfoData, localStorageService, UserApplications){
    this.UserInfoData = UserInfoData;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
    this.userApplications = UserApplications;
}
```

When I give a callback function to the $resource.query() function and wrap it with $.proxy I keep getting this.localstorag is undefined, when I debug it this is a reference to window. So not exactly the behaviour I expected.

Is there any other way to pass 'this' or a reference to the object to the callback function? 
I've allready tried with creating a variable with a reference to this but it doesn't do the trick either :/

```
UserService.prototype.getUserApplications = function(){
    var locale = this.getUserinfoLocale();
    var applications = this.localStorageService.get(Constants.key_applications+locale);
    if(applications !== null){
        return JSON.parse(applications);
    } else {
        return this.userApplications.query({locale: locale}, $.proxy(function(data, locale){
            this.localStorageService.add(Constants.key_applications+locale, JSON.stringify(data));
        }), this);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the comma position and is sending "this" to userApplications' query method, not jQuery's proxy one.

Try this in your "else" block instead:

```
return this.userApplications.query({locale: locale}, $.proxy(function(data, locale){
    this.localStorageService.add(Constants.key_applications+locale, JSON.stringify(data));
}, this));
```